# awk: printing a tab-delimited instead of a space-delimited file

Tags: awk

I am using this awk command to print out certain columns of a file

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$5,log($11),$12}' inputfile > outputfile
```

The inputfile is tab-delimited, and the outputfile is space-delimited. I need the outputfile to be tab-delimited as well. I tried this, but this still gives me a space-delimited file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{print $1,$2,$3,$5,log($11),$12}' inputfile > outputfile
```

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you want `BEGIN { OFS="\t" }`, to set only the output field separator.

Comment: For other beginners like me, this needs to go in the BEGIN block like so: `BEGIN {OFS="\t"}`.

Comment: Thanks @BryanRink, I've incorporated that into my answer.